# How can I zoom in python plot or make it bigger?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, marker

I would like to zoom in a plot, make it bigger and more clear.

Besides that, I would like that the markers (the circle points) be in a different color.

[image: actual plot, that I want to improve]

And here is for example what I would like to have:

[image]

The actual code I am using to plot is the following one:

```
t, y, y_ = integrateB(rkuttaButcher, fNotSimple, 15.9, 0, 1, h, b, b_, A, 0.01, 0.05)

plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.title('Car')

plt.plot(t,y,'ro-', linewidth=0.5, markersize=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure size can be set using

- the `figsize` argument, e.g. for a 10 by 6 inch figure

  ```
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
  ```

  This has to be specified for each figure you draw.
- The `"figure.figsize"` rcParam, putting

  ```
  plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 10,6
  ```

  directly after the pyplot import.

---

Setting the markercolor can be done using `markerfacecolor` (or `mfc`) and `markeredgecolor` (or `mec`)

```
ax.plot([2,2.6,4], markersize=10, marker="s", color="crimson", mfc="gold", mec="gold")
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to draw the marker (the circle points) in a different color?

Comment: Please mind that on this Q&A site, there should be one question per question. "Changing the color" is too broad, but if you have google available you will find a solution.

Comment: I searched for that and found so much answers, but not the one matching my case. Really couldn't find it. I posted a screenshot, to show the way I actually want to have it. 
And sometimes it takes you, and me, a really tiny time-slice to answer it, why should we spend 1h for a simple answer? Thank you in advance

Comment: I updated the answer, but for next time, if you don't find anything (at least the arguments are mentioned in the documentation, but ok), just ask two different questions. The reason is the following: If you cannot find a solution to 2 different problems, how high are the chances that someone else will have exactly those two different problems as well? Zero. However each problem individually asked and answered may be helpful for a lot of people. Also, the user that answers one of the questions might not know the answer to the other one. There are many other reasons, so just ask two questions.